# How to use php var as same as column name in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

How to use php var as same as column name in php mysql ?

When access to this site

```
www.example.com/test.php?column=member_no&id=5
```

I will get `$_GET['column'] = member_no` and `$_GET['id'] = 5`

Then when i test below code why data not update ?

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['column'])."' = '0' WHERE id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."' ";
$dbQuery = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Try this _"UPDATE table SET \`".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['column'])."\` = '0' WHERE id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."'"_

Comment: what error showing ?

Comment: @mongmongseesee, Your answer is waiting for you after your post publish, But you did't react with it, If you don't need the solution then why ask the question and waste my time.

Answer (score 2):

Use of Mysql Field name in PHP has its own convention, you can't use `'` for a filed name, You need to use **`** or left blank.

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET `".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['column'])."` = '0' WHERE id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."'";
$dbQuery = mysql_query($sql);
```

> Note: `mysql_*` is depreciated in upper level PHP version and removed
>   from PHP 7.*, So please avoid use them and start with `mysqli_*` or
>   PDO.

Comment: Note that `mysql_real_escape_string` will not apply proper escaping for *column names*; as the name implies, it escapes for ***string syntax***, not backtick-delimited column syntax. Bottomline: this is vulnerable to SQL injection.